# Particular NServiceBus ServiceControl Stopping

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

i am trying to get ServiceControl in place to enable monitoring of our existing NServicebus infrastructure.

The setup appeared to be OK linking ServiceControl with ServiceInsight and ServicePulse. However ServiceControl is stopping on its own frequently and I don't understand why. I originally had this on my local machine but experienced the same issue so tried on our development server but the same has happened again.

We are using SQLServer transport along with error and auit forwarding if this is relevant.

ServiceControl v1.42.0 / 1b16461

Looking at the logs the following are being reported (small sample), any ideas?:

[Sample of Log Messages](https://file.io/pxuoD0)

Common hings mentioned are "Invalid instance handle", "Error when trying to open a new DocumentStorageActions" and "c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-2.5\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\StorageActions\General.cs:line 76"

Comment: Could you provide ServiceControl logs? Sample log above doesn't give me much to work with. Also, you can run the .exe directly and see what's crashing the process.

Comment: The ServiceControl service can stop on its own when the SQL Database it is using for transport is unreachable for some period time.  This can be due to network problems or a database backup.